# Using Array to find average height

Tags: java

```
public static void main (String args[])
{
    //10 name arrays
    String players[];
    players[0]="Kevin Love";
    players[1]="Kyrie Irving";
    players[2]="Lebron James";
    players[3]="Dion Waiters";
    players[4]="Shawn Marion";
    players[5]="Tristan Thompson";
    players[6]="Anderson Varejo";
    players[7]="Joe Harris";
    players[8]= "Mike Miller";
    players[9] = "Brendan Haywood";
    //10 height arrays in centimeter
    double heights[];
    heights[0]=208;
    heights[1]=191;
    heights[2]=203;
    heights[3]=193;
    heights[4]=201;
    heights[5]=206;
    heights[6]=208;
    heights[7]=198;
    heights[8]=203;
    heights[9]=213;
    //String c= calcAverage(heights);
    //System.out.println("The average of your arrays numbers is: " + c);
}
// for calculating average for heights
public static double calcAverage(double heights) {
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i=0; i < heights.length; i++)
    {
        sum = sum + heights[i];
    }
    double average = sum / (double)heights.length;
    return average;
}
// height more than average
public static double heightAverage(double average)
{
    String heights;
    if (heights>average)
    {
        System.out.println("Players|Heights");
        System.out.println("-----------+-----------");
        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
        for (double c = 1; c <= 45; c += 0.5) {
            double d = (c * 0.381);
            System.out.println(String.format("%-11s|%8s", c,   df.format(d)));
        }
    }
}
```

}

Write a program to read in a series of heights of people in centimeters. I have to output the heights of all those that are above average in height for the group. I did one method for calculating average and another method for doing if statements can u please help me. I have to do this using arrays, therefore for the third method i am trying to make a  chart of players with the heights that are above their average height

Comment: code consist of lot of error

Answer (score 2):

```
public static double calcAverage(double heights)
```

your method is expecting a `double` parameter, not `double[]`. So you cannot pass your `double array` to the method.

The 2nd method: `public static double heightAverage(double average)` needs a return value(`double`), but you didn't return anything.

Comment: @CharanSingh I guess you may want to try `public static double calcAverage(double[] heights)`

Comment: @CharanSingh if the 2nd method is just for outputting the table, you don't need declare the return type at all. that is, you need a `void` method.

Answer (score 0):

in you class there are several errors

```
public static double calcAverage(double heights)
```

you passed `double` instead of `double[]`

forgot to initialize the array

```
String players[]=new String[10];
```

Added int and double values

```
double sum = 0;
    for (int i=0; i < heights.length; i++)
    {
        sum = sum + heights[i];
    }
```

your method `public static double heightAverage(double[] average)`totally confusing

Comment: public static double calcAverage(double[] heights) {
        double sum = 0;
        for (int i=0; i < heights.length; i++)
        {
            sum = sum + heights[i];
        }
        double average = sum / (double)heights.length;
        return average;
    }

Comment: edited version. you better to use any java IDE eclipse netbeans

Answer (score 0):

Since you explicitly asked, I came to see whats the post, but I don't understand what you are up to. I assume something and sharing the fixed snippet, hoping it might help you to code yourself to get what you need.

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

public class Test1 {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        // 10 name arrays
        String players[] = new String[10];
        players[0] = "Kevin Love";
        players[1] = "Kyrie Irving";
        players[2] = "Lebron James";
        players[3] = "Dion Waiters";
        players[4] = "Shawn Marion";
        players[5] = "Tristan Thompson";
        players[6] = "Anderson Varejo";
        players[7] = "Joe Harris";
        players[8] = "Mike Miller";
        players[9] = "Brendan Haywood";
        // 10 height arrays in centimeter
        double heights[] = new double[10];
        heights[0] = 208;
        heights[1] = 191;
        heights[2] = 203;
        heights[3] = 193;
        heights[4] = 201;
        heights[5] = 206;
        heights[6] = 208;
        heights[7] = 198;
        heights[8] = 203;
        heights[9] = 213;


        double average = 203; // you have to calculate average first!

        System.out.println("print all players with their heights");
        System.out.println("Players|Heights");
        System.out.println("---------+---------");
        for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
            DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
            System.out.println(String.format("%-11s|%8s", players[i],
                    df.format(heights[i])));
        }

        System.out.println("****************************");
        System.out.println("****************************");


        System.out.println("print only those players whose height is greater than average");
        System.out.println("Players|Heights");
        System.out.println("---------+---------");
        for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
            printPlayerheights(average, heights[i], players[i]);
        }

    }

    public static void printPlayerheights(double average, double height,
            String player) {
        if (height > average) {
            DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
            System.out.println(String.format("%-11s|%8s", player,
                    df.format(height)));
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
print all players with their heights

Players|Heights
```

---------+---------

```
Kevin Love |     208
Kyrie Irving|     191
Lebron James|     203
Dion Waiters|     193
Shawn Marion|     201
Tristan Thompson|     206
Anderson Varejo|     208
Joe Harris |     198
Mike Miller|     203
Brendan Haywood|     213
```

---

---

```
print only those players whose height is greater than average

Players|Heights
```

---------+---------

```
Kevin Love |     208
Tristan Thompson|     206
Anderson Varejo|     208
Brendan Haywood|     213
```

Comment: can you tell me what is third method and what is first method?

Comment: Updated the answer. BUT ..Man, Please try yourself, I thought of throwing some light from where you can rectify the error and fix yourself. This is not the way to go. With what you got from here from all so far, I am sure you can finish it